# How much a window is resized in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, resize, height

Is there a way to trigger an event in jQuery only when someone resizes a window more than like 50 pixels?

I want to prevent events from triggering when scrolling on mobile browsers. The scrolling tends to resize the window and cause some glitches. I've looked into debounce functions, but they don't totally solve my problem.

Comment: Scrolling shouldn't affect the window size on a mobile browser. Can you give exact details of what the glitches are as it sounds like there may be another issue.

Comment: By coding, what have you tried?

Comment: XY problem i guess: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are testing in chrome for mobile. Chrome hides the nav bar and shows it when you scroll in one direction, when he thinks that you may want to have access to it. when you are working with percentage heights this can be very annoying, I agree with you.

you could do this:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
console.log("initial: "+height);

$(window).on("resize", doStuff);
function doStuff(){
  if( Math.abs(height - window.innerHeight) > 50){
    //really do stuff
    console.log(height - window.innerHeight);
  }
}
```

or with javascript:

```
var height = window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  if( Math.abs(height - window.innerHeight) > 50){
    //fire your code
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the job!! I adjusted your code for checking widths, instead of heights.